# How do I build a docker-compose container from a git-resource in Concourse CI?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, concourse, concourse-git-resource

I am currently trying to build and deploy a dockerized Go project, pulled from a Git repo in using Concourse.

To give you some background about my current setup:

- I got two AWS Lightsail instances set up, both of them using a Docker container to serve Concourse.
- One of those instances is serving the web node, the other one is acting as a worker node, which connects to the web node.

My current pipeline looks like this:

```
resources:
- name: zsu-wasserlabor-api-repo
  type: git
  webhook_token: TOP_SECRET
  source:
    uri: git@github.com:lennartschoch/zsu-wasserlabor-api
    branch: master
    private_key: TOP_SECRET

jobs:
- name: build-api
  plan:
  - get: zsu-wasserlabor-api-repo
    trigger: true
  - task: build
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source: {repository: alpine}
      inputs:
      - name: zsu-wasserlabor-api-repo
      run:
        path: sh
        args: 
        - -c
        - |
          cd zsu-wasserlabor-api-repo
          docker-compose build
```

The problem is that docker-compose is not installed.

I am feeling like I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Could anyone give me a hint?

Best,

Lennart

Answer (score 2):

The pipeline described above specifies that it should use the `alpine` image, which doesn't have `docker-compose` on it.  Thus, you will need to find an image that has `docker-compose` installed on it, but even then, there are additional steps you will need to take to make it work in Concourse (see this [link](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/324) for more details).

Fortunately, someone has made an image available that takes care of the additional steps, with a sample pipeline that you can find here: https://github.com/meAmidos/dcind

---

That being said, if you are simply trying to build a Docker image, you can use the [docker-image-resource](https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource#example) instead and just specify the Dockerfile.